# refresh image when source changed

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page contain Image, the image source is locally,

```
<img src="c:\bla\bla.png" />
```

so, the "bla.png" file is changed, I overwrite the image,

How can I refresh the image in the img control without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Use javascript and a setInterval to change the src attribute to something like c:\bla\bla.png?cnt=1 and increment cnt.

Comment: Not necessary..image automatically changed when src was changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime that the image changes you execute this code:

```
yourImage.src = "http://localhost/image.jpg?" + new Date().getTime();
```

If you can't catch this event, just instantiate an interval

```
setInterval(function(){ yourImage.src = "http://localhost/image.jpg?" + new Date().getTime(); }, 1);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Great Thanks

Comment: Np i like to help

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
let url = 'c:\bla\bla.png', 
    count = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('myimg').src = url + '?cnt=' + count++;
}, 1000);
```

Change the html a little.

```
<img id="myimg" src="c:\bla\bla.png" />
```